# Reuse Model from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a Custom Validator Attribute called RequiredIf inside a Model in my main Web Project and I need to reuse that model in another Model from another project. When I look at the disassembled dll from the Main Project inside the subproject, the Custom Attribute just disappears and the Custom Attribute doesn´t work.

Here goes my structure:

**MainProject**

```
[RequiredIf( "TipoReagendamentoSco", false, "CodigoTipoReagendamento", null, "Tipo Reagendamento é obrigatório")]
[Display(Name = "Tipo Reagendamento:")]
public int CodigoTipoReagendamento { get; set; }
```

**SubProject**

```
public TipoReagendamentoModel TipoReagendamento { get; set; }
```

**Disassembled MainProject.DLL**

```
[Display(Name = "Tipo Reagendamento:")]
public int CodigoTipoReagendamento { get; set; }
```

The Custom Validator Attribute (RequiredIf) went away. But when I use 'Required' from DataAnnotations (not a custom attribute), it works like a charm.

Thanks !

Comment: where have you created this `custom validator attribute`. Is it in a separate class file or within `model` itself??

Comment: I've created in a class inside the MainProject and i´m trying to access the Model (mainproject) from an external project (subproject).

Comment: I found the problem. The parameter 'null' of RequiredIf was wrong. The right parameter is 0. My mistake.